# How to pass parameters from array button

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array with strings of books, and this code which puts each item from the array into a button. How do I get the button to pass a parameter of the string of the button?

```
<p id="bil"></p>
```

```
function nb() {
    for (var i = 0; i < booksInLibrary.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("bil").innerHTML += "<button class='btn' onclick='add()'>" + booksInLibrary[i] + "</button> "
    }
}

var booksInLibrary = [
    "Bambi",
    "The Lord of the Rings",
    "Aladdin",
    "Dune",
    "I, Robot",
    "The Martian"
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by pass the parameter of the string? Do you just mean the text value of the current index? That would be `booksInLibrary[i]`

Comment: I want to send the string of the button to the function add() , is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `onclick='add()'` with `onclick='add(" + i + ")'>"`

Then you can do:

```
var booksInLibrary = [
    "Bambi",
    "The Lord of the Rings",
    "Aladdin",
    "Dune",
    "I, Robot",
    "The Martian"
]

function nb() {
    for (var i = 0; i < booksInLibrary.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("bil").innerHTML += "<button class='btn' onclick='add(" + i + ")'>" + booksInLibrary[i] + "</button> "
    }
}

function add(bookId) {
    var bookTitle = booksInLibrary[bookId]
    // do something with book title
    alert(bookTitle)
}
```

If you really need the book title as a string:

```
var booksInLibrary = [
    "Bambi",
    "The Lord of the Rings",
    "Aladdin",
    "Dune",
    "I, Robot",
    "The Martian"
]

function nb() {
    for (var i = 0; i < booksInLibrary.length; i++) {
        var btn = document.createElement("button")
        btn.innerText = booksInLibrary[i]
        btn.className = "btn"
        btn.onclick = (function(i) {
            add(booksInLibrary[i])
        }).bind(null, i)
        document.getElementById("bil").appendChild(btn)
    }
}

function add(bookTitle) {
    alert(bookTitle)
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure he wants the actual string data being passed over the index position, as that could change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use interpolation to format your text as

```
document.getElementById("bil").innerHTML += `<button class='btn' onclick='add("${booksInLibrary[i]}")'>${ booksInLibrary[i]}</button>`;
```

```js
function nb() {
    for (var i = 0; i < booksInLibrary.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("bil").innerHTML += `<button class='btn' onclick='add("${booksInLibrary[i]}")'>${ booksInLibrary[i]}</button>`;
    }
}

var booksInLibrary = [
    "Bambi",
    "The Lord of the Rings",
    "Aladdin",
    "Dune",
    "I, Robot",
    "The Martian"
]

nb();
```

```html
<p id="bil"></p>
```